# Angular 2 / RXJS - need some help batching requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I keep reading rxjs documentation but getting lost in all the operators..

this is what i got so far

```
  let obs = Observable.from([1, 3, 5])
```

so what i need this to do is `take()` some set amount from the array.  use the results in a post request, when that comes out successful then i need to restart the process.  I want to collect all the results, and keep progress as the process is going (for a progress bar)

I don't need the code for all of that.  what i really need to know is how to use rxjs to split this array up.. send part of it, and restart the process until theres nothing left to send.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
  var _this = this

  function productsRequest(arr) {
    return _this.chainableRequest('post', `reports/${clientId}/${retailerId}/`, loadedProductsReport, {
        'identifiers': arr,
        'realTime': true
      })    
  }

  let arrayCount = Math.ceil(identifiers.length/10)
  let obs = Observable.from(identifiers)            
    .bufferCount(10)
    .concatMap(arr => {
      arrayCount--
      return arrayCount > 0 ? productsRequest(arr) : Observable.empty()
    })


  let subscriber = obs.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value)
  )
```

chainable request method in parent

```
  chainableRequest(method: string, endpoint: string, action: Function, data = {}, callback?: Function){
let body = (<any>Object).assign({}, {
  headers: this.headers
}, data)


return this._http[method.toLowerCase()](`${this.baseUri}/${endpoint}`, body, body)
          .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This largely depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to recursively call an Observable based on some previous Observable and you don't know how many times you're going to call it then use [`expand()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator.

For example this demo recursively creates 5 requests based on the response from the previous call (`count` property):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

function mockPostRequest(count) {
    return Observable.of(`{"count":${count},"data":"response"}`)
        .map(val => JSON.parse(val));
}

Observable.of({count: 0})
    .expand(response => {
        console.log('Response:', response.count);
        return response.count < 5 ? mockPostRequest(response.count + 1) : Observable.empty();
    })
    .subscribe(undefined, undefined, val => console.log('Completed'));
```

Prints to console:

```
Response: 0
Response: 1
Response: 2
Response: 3
Response: 4
Response: 5
Completed
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lKNdR8oeOuB2mrnR3ahQ?p=preview

Or if you just want to call a bunch of HTTP request in order one after another ([`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) operator) or call all of them at once and consume them as they arrive ([`mergeMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operator):

```
Observable.from([
    'https://httpbin.org/get?1',
    'https://httpbin.org/get?2',
    'https://httpbin.org/get?3',
  ])
  .concatMap(url => Observable.of(url))
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Prints to console:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?1
https://httpbin.org/get?2
https://httpbin.org/get?3
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JwZ3rtkiSNB1cwX5gCA5?p=preview

Comment: what im trying to accomplish is take x number of items from array -> pass that into http request. 

wait for http request to finish, and then pass the items again from the start.  I've tried all your examples but not seeing how to make that work for what im trying to do..

Comment: @hamobi Running Observables one at the time can be done with  `concatMap()`. Then you want to restart the process from the same array or what?

Comment: yes i want to restart the process from the same array.  i want to send ten items from the array, then the next ten items and so on.. until i reach the end of the array.  thanks :)

Comment: @hamobi Then use `expand()` and not `concatMap()`

Comment: i've updated my work..  using expand now.  my requests are still firing off all at once.. can you see anything im doing wrong?

Comment: actually I switched it to concatMap and it's working now!