# Chaining http calls on angular2 using observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an angular2 application with a service that makes a HTTP call that has various subscribers (each showing a different piece of info).
Once the first call is completed, I need to make a second independent HTTP call, and based on the values retrieved, filter the array obtained from the **first** call.
Its not working, the subscribers of the second HTTP call, doesn't know to wait and i get an empty list since the array of the first call is not yet there

Im attaching the relevant service

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.initializeAlertService();
    console.log('Started alerts service');
   }

   initializeAlertService() {
        if (!this.allData$) {
          this.allData$ = <BehaviorSubject<Alert[]>> new BehaviorSubject(new Array<Alert>());

          this.http.get(this.url)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server Error'))
            .subscribe(
              allData => {
                this.allData = allData;
                this.allData$.next(allData);
                this.initializeAlertSeverities(); -- I want this to fire when the 'allData' is ready
              },
              error => console.log("Error subscribing to AlertService: " + error)
            );
        }
  }

subscribeToAlertSeverities(): Observable<AlertSeverity[]>  {

    return this.alertSeverities$.asObservable();
  }
```

then on my component i subscribe to the alertSeverities, yet i get not data....

Comment: You might want to take a look at `concat` operator. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html
Here's an SO example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519645/how-can-i-make-one-rxjs-observable-sequence-wait-for-another-to-complete-before

Comment: Can you please provide the code the consumes the data and explain why you think it triggers before the second call is completed?

Comment: `this.initializeAlertSeverities();` is called after the first request finishes.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295717/angular-2-rxjs-need-some-help-batching-requests/40312328#40312328 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797698/observable-continue-calling-api-and-changing-parameters-based-on-condition/39816349#39816349 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566268/angular-2-rxjs-how-return-stream-of-objects-fetched-with-several-subsequent/39578646#39578646

Comment: What is the variable `alertServerities$`. You never define it nor use it to create a subscription.

Comment: @martin I tried the concatMap but in the subscribe part i need to do different operation (after first url call do A and for second url call do B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by passing the result of the http call to a function in the subscribe part of the code

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.initializeAlertService();
    console.log('Started alerts service');
  }

  initializeAlertService() {
    if (!this.alerts$) {
      this.alerts$ = <BehaviorSubject<Alert[]>> new BehaviorSubject(new Array<Alert>());
      this.alertSeverities$ = <BehaviorSubject<AlertSeverity[]>> new BehaviorSubject(new Array<AlertSeverity>());

      this.http.get('first url')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(alerts => {
        this.alerts$.next(alerts);
        this.initializeAlertSeverities(alerts);
      })
    }
  }

  initializeAlertSeverities(alerts){
    this.http.get('second url')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server Error'))
    .subscribe(
      severities => {
        severities.map((severity) => {
          var severityCounter = alerts.filter(alert => alert['severity'] == severity.severityValue).length;
          severity.severityCount = severityCounter;
        });

        this.alertSeverities$.next(severities);
      },
      error => console.log("Error subscribing to Alert Severities: " + error)
    );
  }

  subscribeToAlertSeverities(): Observable<AlertSeverity[]>  {
    //actual subscriber that components subscribe to
    return this.alertSeverities$.asObservable();
  }


  subscribeToAlertService(): Observable<Alert[]> {
    return this.alerts$.asObservable();
  }
```